# Express js routes url to correct page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

URL pattern is `www.example.com/product-name/pid_010101`. URL's first segment is **Product name** and second segment is **Product number**. My app router code is below

```
app.get("/:name?/:id", routes.index);
```

Now my all urls redirect to same page. For example some url like `www.example.com/homepage/banner.html` also redirect to `www.example.com/product-name/pid_010101`

Need to add some Filters in router. **How to route the url to correct page**?

Comment: is banner.html a static asset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write own middleware function that handles the legacy URLs, and place it above the Express router.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (legacySystemHandles(req.url)) {
        // do legacy stuff
    }
    else next(); // pass to the next middleware function
});
app.use(app.router);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `/homepage/banner.html` complies to your route as well.
Therefore you must also specify those routes you want to trigger.
Say for example you have a welcome page.(`/welcome/guest`) or something like that.
You can add another route **above** the general route. specific for that page.

```
app.get("/welcome/guest", routes.welcome);
```

Now this is too much work for all your pages. So you can avoid this with a couple of techniques, one would be to put a static part in the url say:

```
app.get("/product/:name?/:id", routes.product);
```

Comment: my url pattern  "www.example.com/product-name/pid_010101" i can't change to www.example.com/product/product-name/pid_010101

Answer (score 0):

I assume your routes will be:
/coffeemaker/pid_0101222 
/bluemarker/pid_121121
etc. ?

You can use regular expressions for this OR 
this is an example of in method filtering:

```
app.get('/rest/:collection', function(req, res) {
  return routes.rest[req.params.collection](req, res);
});
```

in routes object:

```
 exports.rest = {
  tweets: function(req, res) {
    return twitter.data.load(function(data) {
      return res.json(data);
    }, config.site.tag, req);
  },
  pics: function(req, res) {
    return instagram.data.load(function(data) {
      return res.json(data);
    }, config.site.tag, req);
  },
  repos: function(req, res) {
    return github.data.load(function(data) {
      return res.json(data);
    }, req);
  },
  links: function(req, res) {
    return delicious.data.load(function(data) {
      return res.json(data);
    }, config.site.tag, req);
  }
};
```

:colection is then tweets, pics , or links string
Can you make a list of all your pages?
Maybe I can help you with your routes...

Comment: you see you can use the params who come inside the url and map this on an object.
then your object is your controller actualy.
So in your case: your name param can also be welcome or contact.
you just add the keys to your routes object and for any other product you use another function. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry here also you have some static in first segment of the URL /rest/<somevalue>

Comment: Can you make a list of all pages or routes you'd like to work?

Comment: "/rest" is not neccesairy. you can aply the same technique on your route.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your problem. Is `/homepage/banner.html` a static page? Middlewares work like a filter, you can simply put `express.static` above `express.router`:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
...
app.use(app.router);
app.get("/:name?/:id", routes.index);
```

`banner.html` is in `(APP_DIR)/public/homepage/banner.html`